# C++, find unused code and includes

Tags: c++, eclipse, plugins, find

Are there any no-cost tools (or direct Eclipse CDT plugins) that scan C++ code for unused functions, methods, variables, includes...?

I only found this stuff for C# and Java, but I'd like to have it for C++.

Cppcheck and also compilers can find unused variables in a scope, but they don't find, for example, unused member functions in classes or unused includes in a .cpp file. It would be good to have something like that to find deprecated and old code in the project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ Free alternative to Lint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632057/c-c-free-alternative-to-lint) (or maybe not a duplicate?)

Comment: g++ will catch unused local variables. Just because a (public) member function is unused doesn't mean it shouldn't still remain as part of the class API.

Comment: Be aware of that a lot of these tools define unused include as "compiles when removing this include" which is something different, as each standard c++ header can include any other header, but you should never rely on that. (This might also be true for certain libraries). It seldomly really harms to include files from 3rd party libraries that are not needed in that particular .cpp file of yours.

Comment: @Mark B But it *could* mean that it is not needed anymore.

Comment: @PlasmaHH:  On a large project, you want as little header stuff as you can get away with in each source file, so you don't want to include unnecessary headers.  Not only will each compile take a little longer (and, hence, the whole compile will take significantly longer), but in event of changes you'll be recompiling more than you have to (in your third-party example, changes won't be frequent, but they may happen).  Also, the more headers included, the more chance that something potentially bad in two of them will cause real problems.

Answer (score 3):

A version of "NDepend" exists for C++ ([cppdepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/)). I haven't tried it, but I did use NDepend in the past. It should be good, YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

[Deheader](http://catb.org/~esr/deheader/), by the estimable Eric S Raymond, will find unused includes. For everything else I use Visual Studio's static analysis tools.

Answer (score 1):

[PCLint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/index.htm) is a good one for this kind of static analysis.

Comment: I shoudl have been more clear: I'm looking fore something at no cost (best: OpenSource).